# Upload photos from Android app to Google Cloud Storage/App Engine - illegal character '_'

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I've having trouble uploading photos from my android app to GCS.  I'm able to upload text files but not photos.  I've tried various mime-types as well as different Base64 encoding methods (decodeBase64, encodeBase64URLSafeString, etc...)

I feel like I'm really close.

This is the error message that I receive:

> com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException:
>   Illegal character '_' (code 0x5f) in base64 content  at [Source: N/A;
>   line: -1, column: -1]

I looked at the encoded String and there aren't any '_' in there.

Android code:

```
Activity:
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case 0:
            {

                try
                {



                        InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());

                        tvMessage.setText("Done!");

                        byte[] b = getBytes(is);

                        gaeTask task = new gaeTask();

                        PhotoObject p = new PhotoObject();

                        p.encodeBytes(b);
                        p.setName("picturejpg.jpg");

                        task.execute(p);
                }
}
AsnycTask:
protected String doInBackground(PhotoObject... params)
        {
            String responseMessage = "";

            try
            {
                PhotoObjectEndpoint builder = new PhotoObjectEndpoint(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), new HttpRequestInitializer()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void initialize(HttpRequest arg0) throws IOException
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });

                PhotoObject p = params[0];
                builder.insertPhotoObject(p).execute();

                responseMessage = p.getName() + " was successfully deployed.";
            }
```

GAE/GCS Code:

```
GAE – PhotoObject:
@Entity
public class PhotoObject
{
    public PhotoObject(){}

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    public Key getKey()
    {
        return key;
    }
    public void setKey(Key key)
    {
        this.key = key;
    }

    private String mBytes;

    public byte[] getBytes()
    {
        return decodeBytes();
    }
    public void setBytes(byte[] mBytes)
    {
        this.mBytes = encodeBytes(mBytes);
    }

    private String name;

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private FileType type;


    public FileType getType()
    {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(FileType type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @see #getBytes()
     * @return Base64 decoded value or {@code null} for none
     * 
     * @since 1.14
     */
    public byte[] decodeBytes()
    {
        return com.google.api.client.util.Base64.decodeBase64(mBytes);
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @see #setBytes()
     * 
     *      <p>
     *      The value is encoded Base64 or {@code null} for none.
     *      </p>
     * 
     * @since 1.14
     */
    public String encodeBytes(byte[] bytes)
    {
        //this.mBytes = com.google.api.client.util.Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(bytes);
        this.mBytes = com.google.api.client.util.Base64.encodeBase64String(bytes);

        return this.mBytes;
    }

}

GAE - insertPhotoObject:
try
        {

        final GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(RetryParams.getDefaultInstance());
        GcsFilename name = new GcsFilename("testbucket123", fileName);
        GcsFileOptions.Builder optionsBuilder = new GcsFileOptions.Builder();

        optionsBuilder.mimeType("image/jpg");
            GcsOutputChannel outputChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(name, optionsBuilder.build());
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(Channels.newOutputStream(outputChannel));
            out.write(bytes);
            out.close();

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Resolved!

I had 2 problems.

1. I was encoding the string improperly.  When I actually looked at the outputted JSON, I could see the there were "_" in the string.  I fixed this by using adding the line

   String s = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

I had tried that before but the image still wouldn't display properly.

1. I wasn't wrapping the byte array in a ByteBuffer, before uploading to GCS:

   GcsOutputChannel outputChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(name, optionsBuilder.build());
   outputChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes));
   outputChannel.close();

Comment: I felt alone on the internet until I found your post man, big thanks.

Comment: Seems the methods `encodeXXX` methods of the generated endpoint models internally use `com.google.api.client.util.Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(byteData)` that somehow manages to create invalid base64 content

Comment: Looks like you are using android.util.Base64. If Java 7 use DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(bytes). Java 8 even has java.util.Base64