# Uploading to Blobstore - Android

Tags: android, image, google-app-engine, backend, blobstore

I am trying to create an Android app where people can read short stories. The stories will be in the form of images since it will include some arts to accompany the text. That is the reason of why I decided to use Google App Engine. I want to store the images in the App Engine then let the client device retrieve all the stories(or images). I can then somehow organise the images into the proper sequence (which I have not an idea on how to do).

I am completely new to Cloud computing or doing backend stuff so there is a lot of stuff that I am not wrapping my head around.

I did a tutorial on creating a mobile assistant app. In the end I got it working and deployed to App Engine. Whenever I upload the files I did it through the command line using "appcfg.py" however after looking at Blobstorage it seems to work a bit differently.

How exactly do you upload images to Blobstore? So far all the thing I've read is on uploading data from the client device/web application and I can't seem to find anything that is very detailed on using Blobstore and Android together. What I am trying to ask is, is there a way to upload the images to the Blobstore directly from the command line (if that is possible)? And how to handle those images once it's up in Blobstore?

Can someone give me some advice please?

Comment: Did you read the docs: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/

Comment: I read the tutorial but I don't understand how it all fit together with an Android app. Like I need to create an upload handler but I need to create a JSP page like where should the JSP go? What does it do? I just can't seem to figure out how it all work together in an Android app.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246734/using-blobstore-with-google-cloud-endpoint-and-android