# size limit of mp4 on Google App-Engine Blobstore

Tags: google-app-engine, mp4, blobstore

The developer documentation for the blobstore says

> the maximum size of Blobstore data that can be read by the application
>   with one API call is 32 megabytes.

What does this mean exactly? If I am uploading a video from android to the blobstore, does this mean the max size of the video file is 32MB? How about if I am watching the video from an android device? I am confused about the `on API call` modifier.

Comment: "with one api call". doesn't say anything about what the storage size limit, just that you can't read more than 32meg in a single call.

Comment: @MarcB I don't know much about videos at all, except that I need to play them in my app. So say I have a 250MB video that I need to upload to the blobstore or watch from the datastore (using android's VideoView), how would the 32MB mentioned affect me? Or does it not matter to my case at all? Perhaps my question is more deeply technical than I thought, such as I may need to use chunks? (which I don't know anything about, but I read the word somewhere while researching video streaming)

Comment: I know the question mentioned no code, but please provide some code of how I might upload a 250MB mp4 from android to blobstore. Thanks.

Comment: Let me google that for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246734/using-blobstore-with-google-cloud-endpoint-and-android

Comment: I saw that answer. I wanted to know what role the 32MB played if any when it comes to very large videos files. I guess the answer is none, which leaves me wondering what does it mean?